# Terraform Argument Block as a List of Maps

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to pick up both elements in my `query_string` tuple. However, only the last element is being picked up. Below, is my test/main.tf file:

```json
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.0"

  required_providers {
    aws = ">= 3.58"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

module "test_module" {
  source = "../"

  lb = [
    {
      name                       = "lb-name"
      enable_deletion_protection = true
      internal                   = false
      load_balancer_type         = "application"

      lb_listener = [
        {
          port       = "8080"
          protocol   = "HTTP"
          ssl_policy = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"

          default_action = {
            type  = "redirect"
            order = 1

            redirect = {
              status_code = "HTTP_302"
            }
          }

          lb_listener_rule = [
            {
              action = {
                type = "fixed-response"

                fixed_response = {
                  content_type = "text/plain"
                  message_body = "This is a message body."
                }
              }

              condition = {
                query_string = [
                  {
                    key   = "health"
                    value = "check"
                  },
                  {
                    value = "bar"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my lb.tf file:

```yaml
variable "lb" {
  description = <<DESCRIPTION
  The AWS Elastic Load Balancing v2 module.
  DESCRIPTION
  type    = any
  default = []
}

locals {
  lb_listener_flat_list = flatten([
    for lb in var.lb : [
      for lb_listener in lookup(lb, "lb_listener", []) : {
        lb_name                          = lb.name
        lb_listener_load_balancer_arn    = aws_lb.lb[lb.name].arn
        lb_listener_port                 = lookup(lb, "load_balancer_type", "application") != "gateway" ? lookup(lb_listener, "port", null) : null
        lb_listener_protocol             = lookup(lb, "load_balancer_type", "application") != "gateway" || lookup(lb, "ip_address_type", null) != "dualstack" ? lookup(lb_listener, "protocol", null) : null
        lb_listener_ssl_policy           = lookup(lb_listener, "protocol", null) != "HTTPS" || lookup(lb_listener, "protocol", null) != "TLS" ? lb_listener.ssl_policy : lookup(lb_listener, "ssl_policy", null)
        lb_listener_default_action_type  = lb_listener.default_action.type
        lb_listener_default_action_order = lookup(lb_listener.default_action, "order", null)

        lb_listener_default_action_redirect = lookup(lb_listener.default_action, "redirect", {}) != {} ? {
          lb_listener_default_action_redirect_status_code = lb_listener.default_action.redirect.status_code
        } : null
      }
    ]
  ])

  lb_listener_rule_flat_list = flatten([
    for lb in var.lb : [
      for lb_listener in lookup(lb, "lb_listener", []) : [
        for lb_listener_rule in lookup(lb_listener, "lb_listener_rule", []) : [
          # I've recently added the line below in an attempte to loop through the list of maps for query_string
          for index in range(length(lookup(lb_listener_rule.condition, "query_string", []))) : {
            lb_name                       = lb.name
            lb_listener_rule_index        = index
            lb_listener_rule_listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.lb_listener[lb.name].arn
            lb_listener_rule_action_type  = lb_listener_rule.action.type

            lb_listener_rule_action_fixed_response = lookup(lb_listener_rule.action, "fixed_response", {}) != {} ? {
              lb_listener_rule_action_fixed_response_content_type = lb_listener_rule.action.fixed_response.content_type
              lb_listener_rule_action_fixed_response_message_body = lookup(lb_listener_rule.action.fixed_response, "message_body", null)
            } : null

            lb_listener_rule_condition_query_string = lookup(lb_listener_rule.condition, "query_string", {}) != {} ? {
              lb_listener_rule_condition_query_string_key   = lookup(lb_listener_rule.condition.query_string[index], "key", null)
              lb_listener_rule_condition_query_string_value = lb_listener_rule.condition.query_string[index].value
            } : null
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ])

  lb_map               = { for lb in var.lb : lb.name => lb }
  lb_listener_map      = { for lb_listener in local.lb_listener_flat_list : lb_listener.lb_name => lb_listener }
  lb_listener_rule_map = { for lb_listener_rule in local.lb_listener_rule_flat_list : "${lb_listener_rule.lb_name}-[${lb_listener_rule.lb_listener_rule_index}]" => lb_listener_rule }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "lb_listener" {
  for_each          = local.lb_listener_map
  load_balancer_arn = each.value.lb_listener_load_balancer_arn
  port              = each.value.lb_listener_port
  protocol          = each.value.lb_listener_protocol
  ssl_policy        = each.value.lb_listener_ssl_policy

  default_action {
    type  = each.value.lb_listener_default_action_type
    order = each.value.lb_listener_default_action_order

    dynamic "redirect" {
      for_each = each.value.lb_listener_default_action_redirect != null ? [{}] : []
      content {
        status_code = each.value.lb_listener_default_action_redirect.lb_listener_default_action_redirect_status_code
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "lb_listener_rule" {
  for_each     = local.lb_listener_rule_map
  listener_arn = each.value.lb_listener_rule_listener_arn

  action {
    type = each.value.lb_listener_rule_action_type

    dynamic "fixed_response" {
      for_each = each.value.lb_listener_rule_action_fixed_response != null ? [{}] : []
      content {
        content_type = each.value.lb_listener_rule_action_fixed_response.lb_listener_rule_action_fixed_response_content_type
        message_body = each.value.lb_listener_rule_action_fixed_response.lb_listener_rule_action_fixed_response_message_body
      }
    }
  }

  condition {
    dynamic "query_string" {
      for_each = each.value.lb_listener_rule_condition_query_string != null ? [{}] : []
      content {
        key   = each.value.lb_listener_rule_condition_query_string.lb_listener_rule_condition_query_string_key
        value = each.value.lb_listener_rule_condition_query_string.lb_listener_rule_condition_query_string_value
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb" "lb" {
  for_each                   = local.lb_map
  name                       = lookup(each.value, "name", null)
  enable_deletion_protection = lookup(each.value, "enable_deletion_protection", null)
  internal                   = lookup(each.value, "internal", null)
  ip_address_type            = lookup(each.value, "ip_address_type", null)
  load_balancer_type         = lookup(each.value, "load_balancer_type", null)
}
```

Here is how the `condition` block looks when I run a `terraform plan`:

```json
condition {
  query_string {
    value = "bar"
  }
}
```

Here is how I would like the `condition` block to look:

```json
condition {
  query_string {
    key   = "health"
    value = "check"
  }

  query_string {
    value = "bar"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your code? It won't even compile as it has wrong syntax, e.g. `each.value.lb_listener_rule_action_fixed_response != null [{}] : []` is wrong as there is no such expression. So its not clear how you can even get to applying it. Please make sure that your question factually represents your real code.

Comment: @Marcin, yes, this is my code, redacted. I created this post by eye. I'll edit my post and ensure it's working. My apologies.

Comment: I'm not sure what you redacted. Its still the same to me with same syntax errors.

Comment: @Marcin, it's updated now. I redacted the code when I first published it. My original files are very long.

Comment: How did it go? Still stuck with the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as complex as it is creates the two `query_string` **correctly**:

[image]

The code, in the form posted in the question has **number of issues** and it will not work. But then as you wrote that "My original files are very long. ", I guess that your real code actually works. Thus **I only focused on its verification**, rather then fixing all possible errors as I don't know what is your factual code.

Comment: The files should compile now. I've just tested them now again. But I've noticed both blocks are still created as well. Any idea as to why it only outputs the last block in the `query_string` and not both?

Comment: @user6005619 Again I'm not sure what you changed. I still see lots of issues. For example, you can't use `ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08` with HTTP, you can't redirect port 8080 to 8080 due to infinite loop, and so on. The code as written will never successfully apply. Your `query_string` is fine and it works as seen in the screenshot. I had to fix all the issues to make it work, but my answer only focuses on `query_string`. I don't know what tf plan shows, but tf apply works (after I modified it) and creates the two conditions.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I never tried actually applying it. The values I've inputted are just for testing. I'll give apply a try.

Comment: @user6005619 How did it go? Any luck with the `query_string`?

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow. However, I'm still looking for a way to have this displayed correctly in a Terraform plan. It'll help a lot visually knowing what will be deployed on an apply. Do you have any alternatives in mind that I could try? I'm thinking about switching from a `for_each` argument to a `count` argument for this resource, but I would like to avoid doing this.

Comment: @user6005619 Its difficult to say something more, appart from what I already did. Your code is very, very complex. In the long run I think it will only keep giving you more issues, or anyone who tries to work with you. If its possible, it would be better to re-think your setup and make this code much simpler, easier to read, debug and maintain.

Comment: sorry for the extremely long delay. I've recently resolved my issue and will post it soon.